# SMARTY: How to get and print certain value from an array/object

Tags: php, arrays, printing, smarty, key-value

I want to get [votes] value and use it between `<span></span>` tags in my `.tpl` file. 
[**SEE SCREENSHOT HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXUVd.jpg)

Does anyone have idea how to get it from there?

I know this question may sound stupid, but I am total beginner in Smarty(and php).

Comment: Looks as if you're trying to iterate an object rather than an array ...

Comment: Oops :D
Is there any way to get that value then?

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to simply shortcut this in Smarty.  Depending on version and configuration, you can probably use a PHP tag there, like this:

```
{php}
    echo $object->votes;
{/php}
```

Obviously, this would go in between your SPAN tags.  Note that my Smarty experience is a few years old now.